# React live server is not displaying anything just showing the tab keep on loading

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-live-server

i'm working on a react app (using create react app) but my live server is not working. When ever i start it i.e run the command of npm start it open a browser tab and keep on loading... Anyone knows whats the issue.

Comment: Does it show any errors in your browser's console like chrome console?? Does it say anything in the command line ?

Comment: Nothing it does not show anything

Comment: Empty console with no error. Not showing html not css not any error message on console. Just keep on loading

Comment: Can you delete your `node_modules` folder and re-install dependencies with `npm i`

Comment: i've done that but not solved

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was an infinite loop in my program. I was calling a component inside it. Which was causing the issue.